# Ltspice - Simulation problem of cross regulation in a multiple output flyback

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, ltspice, flyback

I am trying to show the effect of the leakage inductance on a multiple output flyback. According to those documents from Unitrode and texas instrument (this one : https://www.ti.com/lit/ml/slup081/slup081.pdf and from this one : https://www.ti.com/seclit/ml/slup261/slup261.pdf). The current on each output is function of the leakage inductance between the different secondary outputs :

[image]

If we consider the following transformer :

[image]

The equivalent circuit of this transformer is the following. The circuit has beeen normalized for better understanding.

[image]

In the formula above, L1 is equal to Lw1 (the wiring inductance) and L2 is equal to the leakage inductance between the first secondary output and the second secondary output plus Lw2 the wiring inductance on the output of this secondary output. Lw1 and Lw2 refers to the "normalized circuit" figure below

So I have try to see this relation on LTspice, but it actually do not suceed. My PC do its maximum for simulate the circuit but it do not exceed 68 % of the simulation (I m bad in LTspice...) Here is my simulation :

[image]

Is there a better way for simulating the effect of leakage inductance on a multiple output flyback ?

Thank you very much and have a nice day !

Comment: L2 is the coupled inductance i.e. not leakage inductance.

Comment: I will edit my question ;)

Comment: You still need to edit your question and, explain why you are trying to understand two identical secondary DC outputs teed off from one secondary winding.

Comment: Thank you Andy, it was indeed a bad idea !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have there is not a multiple output flyback, but a simple one secondary transformer with two loads. You also have a few quirks that the SPICE world, in general, doesn't like. One of them is not setting `vh` for the VCSW. As the good book says (*LTspice > Circuit Elements > S. ...*, emphasis mine):

> If `Vh` is zero, the switch is always completely on or off depending upon whether the input voltage is above the threshold. If `Vh` is positive, the switch shows hysteresis, as if it was controlled by a Schmitt trigger with trip points at `Vt - Vh` and `Vt + Vh`. [...] *If `Vh` is negative, the switch will smoothly transition between the on and off impedances*.

That smooth transition ensures that the derivatives are smooth and the engine doesn't cough "*timestep too small*" errors, or similar. The solution is simple: set `vh<0`. The same for diodes:

> The parameters `epsilon` and `revepsilon` can be specified to smoothly switch between the off and conducting states.

Some other tweaks won't hurt, such as `Rser` for capacitors or voltage sources, a few changes to make it a true multiple output and a minor adjustment to the value of the leakage inductance (note that I used the formula for 1 pri - 1 sec) and, overall, this is the result that works for me:

[image: fly]

And the source (careful with wrapping):

```
Version 4
SHEET 1 880 680
WIRE 544 -112 480 -112
WIRE 672 -112 608 -112
WIRE 736 -112 672 -112
WIRE 768 -112 736 -112
WIRE 480 -80 480 -112
WIRE 672 -80 672 -112
WIRE 768 -80 768 -112
WIRE 160 -16 -96 -16
WIRE 256 -16 160 -16
WIRE -96 0 -96 -16
WIRE 256 0 256 -16
WIRE 160 16 160 -16
WIRE 480 32 480 0
WIRE 608 32 480 32
WIRE 672 32 672 -16
WIRE 672 32 608 32
WIRE 768 32 768 0
WIRE 768 32 672 32
WIRE 544 96 480 96
WIRE 672 96 608 96
WIRE 736 96 672 96
WIRE 768 96 736 96
WIRE 480 128 480 96
WIRE 672 128 672 96
WIRE 768 128 768 96
WIRE 160 160 160 80
WIRE 256 160 256 80
WIRE 256 160 160 160
WIRE 304 160 256 160
WIRE 352 160 304 160
WIRE 256 192 256 160
WIRE 352 192 352 160
WIRE 208 208 64 208
WIRE 480 240 480 208
WIRE 608 240 480 240
WIRE 672 240 672 192
WIRE 672 240 608 240
WIRE 768 240 768 208
WIRE 768 240 672 240
FLAG -96 80 0
FLAG 64 288 0
FLAG 208 256 0
FLAG 256 272 0
FLAG 352 256 0
FLAG 608 32 0
FLAG 608 240 0
FLAG 736 -112 o1
FLAG 736 96 o2
FLAG 304 160 d
SYMBOL voltage 64 192 R0
WINDOW 3 22 111 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName V1
SYMATTR Value pulse 0 1 0 {tr} {tr} {Ton} {T}
SYMBOL voltage -96 -16 R0
SYMATTR InstName V2
SYMATTR Value 50
SYMBOL sw 256 288 M180
SYMATTR InstName S1
SYMBOL diode 336 256 M180
WINDOW 0 24 64 Left 2
WINDOW 3 24 0 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName D1
SYMBOL ind2 240 -16 R0
SYMATTR InstName L1
SYMATTR Value {L}
SYMATTR Type ind
SYMBOL ind2 496 16 R180
WINDOW 0 36 80 Left 2
WINDOW 3 36 40 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName L2
SYMATTR Value {L}
SYMATTR Type ind
SYMBOL TVSdiode 144 16 R0
SYMATTR InstName D2
SYMATTR Value tvs
SYMBOL diode 544 -128 M90
WINDOW 0 0 32 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 32 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName D3
SYMBOL cap 656 -80 R0
WINDOW 123 23 79 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName C1
SYMATTR Value 5u
SYMATTR Value2 Rser=10m
SYMBOL res 752 -96 R0
SYMATTR InstName R1
SYMATTR Value 20
SYMBOL ind2 496 224 R180
WINDOW 0 36 80 Left 2
WINDOW 3 36 40 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName L3
SYMATTR Value {L}
SYMATTR Type ind
SYMBOL diode 544 80 M90
WINDOW 0 0 32 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 32 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName D4
SYMBOL cap 656 128 R0
WINDOW 123 23 79 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName C2
SYMATTR Value 5u
SYMATTR Value2 Rser=10m
SYMBOL res 752 112 R0
SYMATTR InstName R2
SYMATTR Value 20
TEXT 208 -64 Left 2 !k l1 l2 l3 {cpl}
TEXT -56 -200 Left 2 !.parma L=500u Lleak=5u cpl=sqrt(1-Lleak/L)\n+ f=100k T=1/f Ton=D*T-tr tr=T/1000 D=0.2
TEXT -56 -120 Left 2 !.tran {100/f}
TEXT -56 -296 Left 2 !.model sw sw ron=10m roff=10meg vt=0.5 vh=-0.5\n.model d d ron=10m roff=10meg vfwd=0.7 vrev=1k epsilon=0.1 revepsilon=50m\n.model tvs d ron=0.1 roff=10meg vfwd=100 vrev=100 epsilon=1 revepsilon=1
```

Comment: Thank you very much !

Comment: Thank you very much ! Just a question, I do not like the transformer flyback model of LTspice as it hides several parameters (leakage inductance and magnetizing inductance). Those parameters are linked to the coupling coefficient K but I actually do not understand exactly what is the relation between K and the magnetizing inductance and above all I m not able to demonstrate it... So if you have a document which explains the effect of K on the different parameters it would be nice. It is important to me as I want to see the influence of the leakage inductance on the circuit...

Comment: You cannot move the K factor without moving the leakage inductance and the magnetizing inductance ... What do you think about the model that I used ? I set the "inductance" of the "transformer" very large and add a parallel inductance for symbolized the magnetizing inductance and I alsso add series leakage inductance.

Comment: @Jess Think about the [equivalent schematic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inductance#Equivalent_circuits) ([and below](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inductance#Coupling_coefficient)). `k` just reflects how well two inductors are coupling, but also how bad <- this is the leakage. If the mutual inductance is `M`, and the two windings are `L1` and `L2`, then `k=M/sqrt(L1*L2)`. Also try to read through [this thread](https://www.electronicspoint.com/forums/threads/transformer-coupling-coefficients.66258/page-2). If you don't like the two coupled inductors, use the equivalent one, but...

Comment: ...apply it properly: the mutual inductance is common, and there -- considering a 1 pri + 2 sec trafo -- a star connection forms where the leakage from the primary goes in and the two secondary leakages run out. The way you've drawn it is just 1 pri + 1 sec, because the underlying model is still coupled inductors. If you had given up on those and simply used `L3` (in your picture), then it would have been fine, except then you would have a grounding problem -- that's why coupled inductors are so much easier to work with. So `k` doesn't hide anything, you just have to do a minor calculation.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will try to find more documentation. I really have some troubles to understand clearly this concept.